# problems when trying to overload << operator in c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, iostream

im trying to write a c++ priority Queue implementation.

this is the class of the priority queue element:

```
template <class Priority, class T>
class PriorityQueueElement {

public:
Priority priority;
T* data;

private:
    PriorityQueueElement* next ;
public:

    PriorityQueueElement( const Priority& priority,T data ) :
        priority(priority) ,data(&data) , next(NULL){
    }
    // ... other functions .. //
    template <class P, class Y>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os ,const PriorityQueueElement<P,Y>& element);

};
```

and the function :

```
template<class Priority, class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os ,const PriorityQueueElement<Priority,T>& elemen){
        return os << "[" << elemen.getPriority() << "," << elemen.getData( ) << "]";
}
```

im getting the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    - template<class Priority, class T> std::ostream& mtm::operator<<(std::ostream&, const 
 mtm::PriorityQueueElement<Priority, T>&)
Multiple markers at this line
    - required from 'std::ostream& mtm::operator<<(std::ostream&, const mtm::PriorityQueueElement<Priority, T>&) [with Priority = int; T = int; std::ostream = 
 std::basic_ostream<char>]'
    - required from 'std::ostream& mtm::operator<<(std::ostream&, const mtm::PriorityQueueElement<Priority, T>&) [with Priority = double; T = Student; 
 std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
```

and if i try to use:

```
template <class Priority,class T>
```

i am getting an error about shadowing the template in the class itself

thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, complete example so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Your constructor is taking the address of a passed-by-value parameter and storing it in a class member. That's...bad.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and modified a bit( for test )

```
template<class Priority, class T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const PriorityQueueElement<Priority, T>& elemen)
    {
        return os << "[" << elemen.priority << "," << *elemen.data << "]";
    }
```

And its working, in main i put:

```
PriorityQueueElement<int, const char*> x( 1, "fsdfsdfsd" );
cout << x;
```

and it gave me output: [1,fsdfsdfsd]

tested on visual studio 2013.
Problemem probably is somewhere else